# ViewBag multiple SelectList for dropdown list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, selectlist, viewbag

I am trying to use dropdownList with two foreign keys which are modelId, and categoryId.
And I am using ViewBag with selectList.

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.categoryId = new SelectList(db.Category, "categoryId", "name");
        ViewBag.modelId = new SelectList(db.Model, "modelId", "name");
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Product/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Product.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
        ViewBag.categoryId = new SelectList(db.Category, "categoryId", "name", product.categoryId);
        ViewBag.modelId = new SelectList(db.Model, "modelId", "name", product.modelId);
        return View(product);
    }
```

And here is my Create.cshtml.

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("categoryId", "--Select--")
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("modelId", "--Select--")
    </div>
```

When I press submit button, error come up, 
'An item with the same key has already been added'
What is problem? Is it problem with in Model?

Here is my models.

```
--Prodruct.cs--

public class Product
{
    [Key] public int productId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select category")]
    public int categoryId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select model")]
    public int modelId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Model name")]
    public String model { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
}

--Category.cs--
public class Category
{
    [Key] public int categoryId { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
}

--Model.cs--
public class Model
{
    [Key] public int modelId { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
}

--RentalDB.cs--
public class rentalDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Model> Model { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Cart { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Where it is wrong? Index page in Create can get category data and model data. However, when I submit it, it has error, 'An item with the same key has already been added'.
Could you help me where has got problem?
Thank you.

--added more coding--

I am using this LINQ. Probably here has problem.

How can I add 'Model' entity in here?

```
var product = from a in db.Product.Include(a => a.Category)
                      select a;
```

Comment: I added a detailed answer on how it could be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would have done it..

I would suggest that you don't send your domain models to the view, but rather create a view model for each view.  Doing it this way you will only include what is needed on the screen.

Create a new view model for your Create view:

```
public class ProductCreateViewModel
{
     // Include other properties if needed, these are just for demo purposes

     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string SKU { get; set; }
     public string LongDescription { get; set; }

     // This is the unique identifier of your category,
     // i.e. foreign key in your product table
     public int CategoryId { get; set; }
     // This is a list of all your categories populated from your category table
     public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }

     // This is the unique identifier of your model,
     // i.e. foreign key in your product table
     public int ModelId { get; set; }
     // This is a list of all your models populated from your model table
     public IEnumerable<Model> Models { get; set; }
}
```

Category class:

```
public class Category
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Model class:

```
public class Model
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In your Create view you would have the following:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.ProductCreateViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     <table>
          <tr>
               <td><b>Category:</b></td>
               <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoryId,
                         new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name", Model.CategoryId),
                         "-- Select --"
                    )
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CategoryId)
               </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td><b>Model:</b></td>
               <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ModelId,
                         new SelectList(Model.Models, "Id", "Name", Model.ModelId),
                         "-- Select --"
                    )
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ModelId)
               </td>
          </tr>
     </table>

     <!-- Add other HTML controls if required and your submit button -->
}
```

Your Create action methods:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     ProductCreateViewModel viewModel = new ProductCreateViewModel
     {
          // Here you do database calls to populate your dropdowns
          Categories = categoryService.GetAllCategories(),
          Models = modelService.GetAllModels()
     };

     return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductCreateViewModel viewModel)
{
     // Check that viewModel is not null

     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          viewModel.Categories = categoryService.GetAllCategories();
          viewModel.Models = modelService.GetAllModels();

          return View(viewModel);
     }

     // Mapping
     Product product = ...  // Do your mapping here

     // Insert product in database
     productService.Insert(product);

     // Return the view where you need to be
}
```

I would also recommend that you use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to do the mappings for you between your domain model and view model.  I would also recommend that you look at [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) to take care of your view model validations.

I hope this helps.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

The service that was used to get all the categories could look like this:

```
public class CategoryService : ICategoryService
{
     private readonly ICategoryRepository categoryRepository;

     public CategoryService(ICategoryRepository categoryRepository)
     {
          // Check if category repository is not null, throw exception if it is

          this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
     }

     public IEnumerable<Category> GetAllCategories()
     {
          return categoryRepository.GetAllCategories();
     }
}
```

categoryRepository is injected by [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/).

Category service interface:

```
public interface ICategoryService
{
     IEnumerable<Category> GetAllCategories();
}
```

I currently still use `Entity Framework 4.1` code first.

My category repository:

```
public class CategoryRepository : ICategoryRepository
{
     MyContext db = new MyContext();

     public IEnumerable<Category> GetAllCategories()
     {
          return db.Categories
               .OrderBy(x => x.Name);
     }
}
```

My category repository interface:

```
public interface ICategoryRepository
{
     IEnumerable<Category> GetAllCategories()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Do you know any example of ViewModel? I think I need to know ViewModel more details. If you know some websites, please let me know. I could not understand about ViewModel properly.. If you have know any ViewModel tutorial, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure.  Just Google it.  Basically a view model contains only the fields that you want to use on your view, for example, if you want to add a new user then you would have fields like just first name, last name and age instead of using everything in your user object.

Comment: The field what I want to add it by using ViewModel, is it same as field name in the original entity? I am trying to understand ViewModel how it does work. In your coding, 'viewModel.Categories = categoryService.GetAllCategories();' How can I declare categoryService?

Comment: It doesn't have to be the same, but I normally keep it the same for mapping purposes.  You can have FirstName in your User class, and NickName in your view model.  You must just make sure that you do the mapping correctly between the 2 fields with different names.

Comment: I iwll update, please up my answer because I'm giving more than what was asked :)

Comment: I have updated the answer.  If you are still unclear then I would suggest you ask a new question.  All the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test
{
    rentalDB db = new rentalDB();
    public Product LoadProductById(int pId)
    {
        return db.Products.Include(p => p.Model).Include(p => p.Category).Where(p => p.productId == pId).SingleOrDefault();
    } // To get specific product.

    public IEnumerable<Product> LoadAllProducts()
    {
        return db.Products.Include(p => p.Model).Include(p => p.Category).ToList();
    } // To get all products.
}
```

I have changed your DbSet to Products make it more clear. This is how you load all the references for one product or all products, in order to iterate over them.